# Automatically loading and running an Outlook Add-In

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, office-addins

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/activation-rules), you should be able to activate an Outlook add-in when a user enters "Compose" mode by specifying an Activation Rule.

In my manifest, I have

```
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
```

This works when you launch the add-in from the app bar, which opens a task pane to the right. However, I want it to launch automatically when a compose window is open and not open a task pane.

Is this possible? And if so, how can one accomplish this?

Here is the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp">
      <Id>dedf4528-4a6e-443b-8763-4ec32c340240</Id>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
      <ProviderName>Contoso, Inc.</ProviderName>
      <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
      <DisplayName DefaultValue="HelloWorld" />
      <Description DefaultValue="HelloWorld"/>
      <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox" />
      </Hosts>
      <Requirements>
        <Sets>
          <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
        </Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
          <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://l.recognizeapp.com:50000/outlook-addin"/>
          </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
      </FormSettings>
      <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" /> 
      <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
    </OfficeApp>
```

And here is the source location:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <style>
    html, body, #wrapper {
      min-height: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
    }

    p {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #888;
    }

    #wrapper {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: .5s opacity linear;
      transition: .5s opacity linear;
    }

    #wrapper.loaded {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    #wrapper .inner {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .recognize {
      color: #1568A6;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="wrapper" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: 100%; min-width: 100%">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="/assets/icons/outlook-progress.gif" alt="Loading Recognize">
      <p>Loading <span class="recognize">Recognize</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "outlook-load" %>
  <script>
  var item;

  Office.initialize = function () {
      item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
      // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
      $(document).ready(function () {
          // After the DOM is loaded, app-specific code can run.
          // Insert data in the top of the body of the composed 
          // item.
          prependItemBody();
      });
  }

  // Get the body type of the composed item, and prepend data  
  // in the appropriate data type in the item body.
  function prependItemBody() {
      item.body.getTypeAsync(
          function (result) {
              if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                  write(asyncResult.error.message);
              }
              else {
                  // Successfully got the type of item body.
                  // Prepend data of the appropriate type in body.
                  if (result.value == Office.MailboxEnums.BodyType.Html) {
                      // Body is of HTML type.
                      // Specify HTML in the coercionType parameter
                      // of prependAsync.
                      item.body.prependAsync(
                          '<b>Greetings, '+Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress+'</b>',
                          { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html, 
                          asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                          function (asyncResult) {
                              if (asyncResult.status == 
                                  Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                  write(asyncResult.error.message);
                              }
                              else {
                                  // Successfully prepended data in item body.
                                  // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                  // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                              }
                          });
                  }
                  else {
                      // Body is of text type. 
                      item.body.prependAsync(
                          'Greetings, '+Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress+":",
                          { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text, 
                              asyncContext: { var3: 1, var4: 2 } },
                          function (asyncResult) {
                              if (asyncResult.status == 
                                  Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                  write(asyncResult.error.message);
                              }
                              else {
                                  // Successfully prepended data in item body.
                                  // Do whatever appropriate for your scenario,
                                  // using the arguments var3 and var4 as applicable.
                              }
                           });
                  }
              }
          });

  }

  // Writes to a div with id='message' on the page.
  function write(message){
      document.getElementById('message').innerText += message; 
  }

  </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

This code is a mashup of the manifest from [here](https://github.com/jasonjoh/hello-world-addin/blob/master/HelloWorld.xml) and the source location code from [here](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/insert-data-in-the-body?product=outlook)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible? And if so, how can one accomplish this?

No this is not possible. The design of the Office.js API add-in is required user invocation. For Outlook add-in you may use ["pinnable" taskpane](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/26/pinnable-taskpane-in-outlook-2016/) feature to keep your add-in open when user switch from message to message, but this is not related to compose and anyway have to be initiated by user at the beginning.

Comment: Isn't there a way to activate add-in when you highlight text? Wondering if there are other potentials hooks to link into.

Comment: @PeterP. "Activate" = make it available for end user (display button or link to add-in); Start add-in is only by user invocation; user choose to run your add-in or not. This is design approach of Office.js API. Automatic invocation of the add-ins (event driven invocation) is for COM/VSTO technology. When user highlight text, no add-in will start. In the same time if user already started an add-in, add-n code may access highlighted text. Hope it clarify the answer.